# Connect QAction to private slot in Design?

Tags: qt

So I have a `QAction` menu item I'd like to connect to this slot:

```
private slots:
    void Open();
```

(trying to avoid `Connect` boilerplate and stuff)

In the designer it never shows up, the only effective way I've found is as follows:

- connect to whatever slot visible in *Design*
- manually edit the `.ui` file to `<slot>Open()</slot>`

This works but I was wondering if I didn't miss something for it to popup directly in the signals and slots editor and avoid this manual operation ?

Comment: There is an auto connect feature of _uic_, basically slots will be connected automatically if you rename them with this pattern: on_UIELEMENTNAME_SIGNALNAME(SIGNALPARAMS)
Read more here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect

Comment: Works amazing, post an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool, i wasn't really sure that is what you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt (uic) has an auto connect feature. You will need to follow a pattern for the slots to be connected automatically, the pattern is: `on_UIELEMENTNAME_SIGNALNAME(<SIGNALPARAMS>)` Read more in the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect)